# Interaction effect in logistic regression

Tags: logistic, statistical-significance, interaction, differences, main-effects

I have applied logit model, where my dependent variable is Emp (Employment) 1 if employed otherwise 0, and used level of education and Health status as independent variables where:

Education consist 6 categories i.e. 1=No Edu, 2= Primary or less Edu, 3=junior Secondary Edu, 4=Senior Secondary Edu, 5=college Edu, and 6=university or equal Edu.
Similarly Health status consists 4 categories: Unhealthy=1, General=2, relatively healthy=3, and very healthy=4.

As I ran logistic regression with no interaction terms I got the significant positive effect (positive coefficients) of both Education and Health on employment status. as I included interaction terms (interaction effect) in my model I found the following coefficients of main effect and interaction effect

**Main effect:**

```
Edu=1 (base),  
Edu=2 (-.0163406),  
Edu=3 (-.2675933**),  
Edu=4 (-.5218183**),  
Edu=5     (.4170227),  
Edu=6 (.0501755)     
unhealhy=1 (base),  
general=2 (.1313351),  
relatively health=3 (-.1436309),  
very health=4 (-.2062591)
```

**Interaction effect:**

```
Edu#Health   
Edu2#general =(-.0040633),  
Edu2#relatively healthy = (.5048051***),  
Edu2#very healthy = (.7818021***),   
Edu3#general = (.0475367),  
Edu3#relatively healthy= (.7332412***),  
Edu3#very healthy (=.9944945***),   
Edu4#general = (.5539992***),  
Edu4#relatively healthy = (1.023986***),  
Edu4#very healthy = (.9342315***),  
Edu5#general= (-.2833318),  
Edu5#relatively healthy = (.2789528),  
Edu5#very healthy= (.6588221),  
Edu6#general= (.6008378),   
Edu6#relatively healthy =(.9638944***),  
Edu6#very healthy = (.714199**)
```

insignificant positive coefficients, significant positive coefficients, insignificant negative coefficients, and significant negative coefficients.

Now I am confuse, how to interpret these results with strong arguments?
Waiting of your valuable comments.

Comment: Rephrase the question without referring to arbitrary statistical "significance".  And make sure you don't remove variables from the model once you have specified them, i.e., don't use p-values for model selection.

Comment: sorry I don't get your point. can you please elaborate?

Comment: Statistical "significance" has been [roundly criticized](https://www.amstat.org/asa/files/pdfs/P-ValueStatement.pdf) and you seem to be putting a lot of emphasis on null hypothesis significance testing, which I personally would try to avoid.